# Render layers: what is All Z, Zmask and Mask Layer

Tags: render-layers

Can anyone elaborate on what "All Z", "Zmask" and "Mask Layers" actually mean, giving some easy examples? I can see the pop-up explanations in Blender, but I am completely confused as to what it actually does (e.g. how it "masks out", what are solid z values, what in "fills in" the values of invisible meshes with and how it relates to masking, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

When "Mask Layers" are used, any render information from the selected layer is omitted from the active render layer.

In blender Z is generally used to determine depth and distance away from the camera. I can only assume "Zmask" would be omitting things base on distance depth away from camera.

I do not have an answer for "All Z".